# Lazy reads of custom types in Racket

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to Racket, and I am trying to write a function to read the lines of a file, parse each line into a `struct`, and return a lazy sequence of my data type. Here is a simple example of my input format (a matrix with row and column names). My actual input format also includes a header line, which I am omitting here, and consists of very large files, which is why I need the laziness.

`R1 1.0 2.3 1.2
R2 1.2 3.1 3.4`

Here is my latest attempt:

```
(struct row (key data))

(define (read-matrix in)
  (for [(line (in-lines in))]
    (let ([fields (string-split line "\t")]
      (row (first fields) (list->vector (map string->number (rest fields))))
      )))
```

I have also tried numerous other approaches including using `call-with-input-file`. My problem with the approach above is that if I use `#lang racket` it isn't lazy, and with `#lang lazy` `string-split` isn't defined. I should add that in my use case, the semantics I want is to close the port when the entire sequence has been consumed, because I can guarantee that either the whole sequence will be consumed, or the program will terminate.

So, am I on the right track? What approach should I take to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was composing this answer off-line, and came back to find you'd mostly answered it already. I'll post anyway in case the details are helpful to anyone.

---

If you really need `#lang lazy`, and want to use `string-split`, I think you can simply `(require racket/string)` to use it?

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "lazy", here. Using `in-lines` will not suck the entire file into memory, if that's your concern. It will process things one line at a time.

One thing you could do is define a helper function, that handles reading and parsing the line, checking for `eof`, and closing the input port automatically:

```
(struct row (key data)
        #:transparent)

;; Example couple lines of input to use below.
(define text "R1 1.0 2.3 1.2\nR2 1.2 3.1 3.4")

;; read-matrix-row : input-port? -> (or/c eof row?)
;;
;; Given an input port, try to read another row.
(define (read-matrix-row in)
  (match (read-line in)
    [(? eof-object?)
     (close-input-port in)
     eof]
    [line (match (string-split line " ")
            [(cons key data)
             (row key (list->vector (map string->number data)))])]))
```

You could use this function in a number of ways. One way is with `in-producer`:

```
;; Example use with in-producer:
(let ([in (open-input-string text)])
  (for/list ([x (in-producer read-matrix-row eof in)])
    x))
;; => (list (row "R1" '#(1.0 2.3 1.2))
;;          (row "R2" '#(1.2 3.1 3.4)))
```

That example uses `for/list` to make `list`. Of course if you have a giant input file, that will yield a giant `list`.  But you could display them one by one, or write them one by one to a file or database:

```
;; Example use, displaying one by one.
(let ([in (open-input-string text)])
  (for ([x (in-producer read-matrix-row eof in)])
    (displayln x))) ;or write to some file, for example
```

If instead you prefer a `stream` interface, it's easy to create a stream from any sequence including `in-producer':

```
;; If you prefer a stream interface, we can use sequence->stream to
;; transform the producer sequence into a stream:
(define (matrix-row-stream in)
  (sequence->stream (in-producer read-matrix-row eof in)))

;; Example interactive use of the stream
(define stm (matrix-row-stream (open-input-string text)))
(stream-empty? stm)                     ;#f
(stream-first stm)                      ;(row "R1" '#(1.0 2.3 1.2))
(stream-empty? (stream-rest stm))       ;#f
(stream-first (stream-rest stm))        ;(row "R2" '#(1.2 3.1 3.4))
(stream-empty? (stream-rest (stream-rest stm))) ;#t
```

Comment: Yes, indeed this is almost exactly what I ended up with (first using in-producer, then switching to generators because they are nicer to work with). Nevertheless, you gave some nice pointers I wasn't aware of, like for/list.

Although I must say, the fine distinctions between streams and sequences remain a little opaque to me. In most languages, a "stream" is a stream of bytes or text, not arbitrary types. And incidentally, your blog is one place Google led me to in my quest to solve this problem ;) Thanks!

Comment: Also for posterity I will add that I was getting errors when trying to require racket/string in ```#lang lazy```.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the functions from [SRFI-13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html), which is a string manipulating library also available in `#lang lazy`:

```
(require srfi/13)
```

And then do this:

```
[fields (string-tokenize line)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately found that I was taking the wrong approach entirely, and didn't even need to use #lang lazy, but this put me on the track to finding that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I found that the answer was to use Racket's sequence, streams, and generator libraries for this kind of thing. The generators are especially nice, allowing a simple Python-like "yield" function. These features allow lazy sequences without full-on lazy evaluation as provided by `#lang lazy`.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html